# What is the total number of stars in the universe?

Tags: star, universe

I mean a total number of stars, not the only ones that we can see.

Comment: We don't know how big the universe is, so your question is currently unanswerable. But we suspect from curvature measurements that the universe is infinite in size, and if that's the case, the number of stars is also infinite.

Comment: You might ask, what is the count of the stars in the visible Universe. Roughly 1 mol.

Comment: See https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/868/how-many-sun-like-stars-are-there-in-the-universe https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/9917/are-there-more-stars-than-all-the-words-ever-spoken-by-humans

Comment: You also might want to consider simultenaity or lack thereof.  Lots of stars we "see" don't exist any more.